# How do I use Get-AdObject with an -LDAPFilter on proxyAddresses?

Tags: active-directory, powershell, exchange, ldap, microsoft-office-365

I'm trying to search for SMTP addresses using an LDAPFilter on ADObject

```
Get-AdObject  -properties * -LDAPFilter "(proxyAddresses=alert.haveibeenpwned@test.edu)"
```

I understand that some of this is possible with GetADUser and Get-Mailbox, or even with the -Filter with the `-anr` command. However for consistency I'd prefer to use native LDAP with the Get-AdObject command.

How can I search a multivalued property, like proxyAddresses using Get-AdObject?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Get-ADObject -Properties * -Filter {ProxyAddresses -eq "smtp:email@yourdomain.com"}
Get-ADObject -Properties * -LDAPFilter "(proxyAddresses=smtp:email@yourdomain.com)"
```

When filtering on multivalued properties, the filter is satisfied if any of the values matches the search string.

But please note the syntax `smtp:email@yourdomain.com`; the `ProxyAddresses` attribute values always have the `smtp:` prefix (or a different prefix for other address types, like SIP or X400).

Comment: For @Ran Dom's sake, you can clean up the output by adding " | Select-Object Name,ProxyAddresses" to the end of these commands.

Comment: Of course, if you simply need to display it; but maybe you need to do something else with the results :)

Comment: Absolutely agree. Just adding that tip in case he had a follow-up question about the output.